# Move text strings into a separate file

Tags: php

So I made a content management system for myself, and recently, a friend wants to use it for his website as well. I made it with adaptation in mind, however, I kindof want to go through all the error strings and message strings and aggregate them into one file. What's the best way to do this? Some sort of text class? I just want one location where I can edit all the messages. For some stuff I am currently using DEFINE, which I know is bad practice.

Comment: You could use get_defined_vars() and get_defined_constants(), but it only works within the scope of the call...

Answer (score 1):

[Laravel](https://laravel.com/) does this by creating a series of files which look like this:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Language Lines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following language lines are used during authentication for various
| messages that we need to display to the user. You are free to modify
| these language lines according to your application's requirements.
|
*/

'failed' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
'throttle' => 'Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.',

];
```

WordPress on the other hand doesn't do it at all for the strings in the original language. Translations in WP are handled through [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), which is a tool made for this purposes. With gettext you automatically generate a `.pot` file using a tool, and that file contains all the strings you have called through your code. The calls in WP are made with `_e("String to be translated and echoed")` or `__("String to be translated and returned")`, so it's super easy to use. It also supports more advanced features like correctly managing plural forms.

Now it really depends what you prefer doing. You could also use gettext in a way similar to a hash: `__("error_invalid_data")` and populate the files with the appropriate sentence, but I don't think there is really a 'correct' way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is some approaches that I can suggest:

**1- Using arrays**

You can define an array in a file, containing all of your messages around the system, having keys that is a short description of each message. So you can include this file in all pages, and echo messages everywhere needed.

I've seen this approach in many real cases, so it seems to be good for small and medium amount of data.

**2- Using Gettext**

There is a more standard way to do that, and it is called **Gettext**. This is a library published by GNU that is widely used in many applications, for globalization and customization. It is already used in many large cases, like Wordpress. This method stores messages in a separate file, called PO files. These files can be loaded and used easily in PHP using built-in functions.

It is harder to implement, but much better in huge amount of data.

More information on this:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html